# How to add data manually to Google analytics Event?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any way to add my data manually on https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web ?

My report displays no row and I want to add some sample data.

[image]

Comment: Simplest way, if you're not concerned about volume, is to send in hits with `ga('send','event','category','action','label')` through the console.

Comment: which console, and where to type with that? Is there anyway to send by c# code?

Comment: dev console. You'll probably have to Google around to see how to do this through C#, probably using the GA API.

Comment: Sorry but I dont see any where to send it. The url is https://console.developers.google.com/home ?

Comment: Developer console for any web browser. Like for Chrome hit F12.

Comment: I receive an error: ga is not defined.

Comment: @ANguyen, open the page where your GA tracking code is integrated (or create an empty HTML page with the tracking code). "ga is not defined" because not tracker instance has been created. Easiest way is to copy the code from the GA propery settings, paste it to an HTML page, call that page in the browser and then run your command from the console.